# random a few data and sum up the values from corresponding row

Tags: database, vb.net, ms-access-2010

I have a database which looks like this

```
+----------+--------+-----------+
| WorkerID | TaskNo | TimeTaken |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 111      | 1      | 7.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 114      | 1      | 2.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 111      | 2      | 3.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 112      | 2      | 1.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 111      | 3      | 2.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 112      | 3      | 4.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 113      | 3      | 3.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
| 112      | 4      | 3.5       |
+----------+--------+-----------+
```

-and the list goes on-

With much help, i'm finally able to display it on vb like

```
+--------+------------+------------------+
| TaskNo | NumWorkers | WorkersAvailable |
+--------+------------+------------------+
| 1      | 2          | 111, 114         |
+--------+------------+------------------+
| 2      | 2          | 111, 112         |
+--------+------------+------------------+
| 3      | 3          | 111, 112, 113    |
+--------+------------+------------------+
| 4      | 1          | 112              |
+--------+------------+------------------+
```

lets say i'm able to generate out 1 random number from each row,

- row 1 - 114
- row 2 - 111
- row 3 - 111
- row 4 - 112

it will be displayed as in a string format which is separated by a comma.

114, 111, 111, 112

The problem now is how do i know which is the corresponding value from the same row. like for example

114, 111, 111, 112=

> 2.5 + 3.5 + 2.5 + 3.5 = 12

how do i display the 12? Any help will be kindly appreciated

**My Codes**

Sub RefreshLv()

```
        Using conn = New OleDbConnection
            conn.ConnectionString = myConString
            conn.Open()

            Dim dt As New System.Data.DataTable("ListInfo")
            Using da

                ' fill the DataTable with three columns, the third column being a placeholder that we will fill in below
                Dim Sql As String = ("SELECT [TaskNo], COUNT(*) AS NumWorkers, '' AS WorkersAvailable " & "FROM ScheduleInfo GROUP BY [TaskNo]")
                da.SelectCommand = New OleDbCommand(Sql, conn)
                da.Fill(dt)

                Using cmd2 = New OleDbCommand()

                    ' create a Prepared Statement that we will use for each iteration
                    cmd2.Connection = conn
                    cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT [WorkerID] FROM ScheduleInfo " & "WHERE [TaskNo] = ? " & "ORDER BY [WorkerID]"
                    cmd2.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer)
                    cmd2.Prepare()

                    LstViewScheduleInfo.Columns.Add("TaskNo", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                    LstViewScheduleInfo.Columns.Add("No of Workers", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)
                    LstViewScheduleInfo.Columns.Add("Workers Available", 150, HorizontalAlignment.Center)

                    ' foreach row of the DataTable, build the string of WorkerID values
                    Dim RandomEmployee As New List(Of Integer)
                    Dim rnd As New Random

                    For Each dr As System.Data.DataRow In dt.Rows

                        Dim ListEmployee As New List(Of Integer)
                        Dim workerList As String = ""
                        cmd2.Parameters(0).Value = dr("TaskNo")
                        Using rdr As OleDbDataReader = cmd2.ExecuteReader()

                            While rdr.Read()
                                ListEmployee.Add(rdr("WorkerID"))
                                workerList += ", " & rdr("WorkerID")
                            End While
                        End Using

                        ' remove leading ", "
                        'Dim Qpass As String
                        dr("WorkersAvailable") = workerList.Substring(2)
                        Dim randomvalue As Integer = ListEmployee(rnd.Next(0, 2))
                        'Qpass = randomvalue.ToString()
                        'MessageBox.Show(Qpass)
                        RandomEmployee.Add(randomvalue)
                    Next
                    Dim zxc = String.Join((","), RandomEmployee.ToArray())
                    LblRandom1.Text = zxc

                End Using

                ' for demo purposes, just dump the DataTable to the console
                For Each dr As DataRow In dt.Rows()
                    Dim lst As ListViewItem
                    lst = LstViewScheduleInfo.Items.Add(dr(0))

                    For i As Integer = 1 To dt.Columns.Count - 1
                        lst.SubItems.Add(dr(i))
                    Next
                Next

            End Using
            conn.Close()
        End Using


    End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

        RefreshLv()

 End Sub
    Private Sub BtnRandom_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles BtnRandom.Click

        LstViewScheduleInfo.Clear()
        RefreshLv()

    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: please show the SQL and code you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are already looping through the Rows in your DataTable to pull out the [WorkerID] values for each [TaskNo]. You can simply retrieve the corresponding [TimeTaken] values at the same time. That is, instead of

```vb
cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT [WorkerID] FROM ScheduleInfo " & "WHERE [TaskNo] = ? " & "ORDER BY [WorkerID]"
```

you can do

```vb
cmd2.CommandText = "SELECT [WorkerID], [TimeTaken] FROM ScheduleInfo " & "WHERE [TaskNo] = ? " & "ORDER BY [WorkerID]"
```

Then, in addition to randomly selecting a [WorkerID] value for each [TaskNo] and adding it to a List you can also add the corresponding [TimeTaken] value to another List.

After you have run through all of the [TaskNo] values you will have your Lists of randomly-selected [WorkerID] values and their corresponding [TimeTaken] values. You can get the total time by adding up the [TimeTaken] values in the list.

Comment: @Crayon Yes, you can create a `ListTimeTaken` just like you've created a `ListEmployee`, and another list for `RandomTimeTaken` just like you have one for `RandomEmployee`. (You'll need to use the same "random" index for both, so save your `.rnd.Next()` result to a variable and then use the variable to pull a selected value out of both `ListEmployee` and `ListTimeTaken`.)

Comment: i get the concept now. can i say randomvalue is the variable to store the random value. but i don't understand how can i pull out the related time from it? or do i have to pull the same value out at the same time using .rnd.next()?

Comment: @Crayon You could just do something like `Dim randomIndex As Integer = rnd.Next(...insert appropriate values here...)`, then do `RandomEmployee.Add(ListEmployee(randomIndex))` and `RandomTimeTaken.Add(ListTimeTaken(randomIndex))`.

Comment: thanks alot man! now i understand what you meant. really appreciate your help. may god bless you

Comment: sorry to disturb you, i realise if i put **Dim randomvalue As Integer = rnd.Next(0, 2)** it will only random between two employee, and the 3rd employee won't even be random. However if i put (0, 3) my first row will be out of range since there's only two values. i've tried searching for solutions but can't seems to find any similar stuff.

Comment: @Crayon You already have the number of workers as a column in your DataTable, so you can probably just use `Next(0,dr("NumWorkers"))` instead of `Next(0,2)`.

Comment: WOW THANKS ALOT! you really helped me learn a lot on my project